# Alternative complex analysis proof of Fundamental Theorem of Algebra

Tags: complex-analysis

My classmate and I working on the following problem from Conway's *Functions of a Complex Variable I* (p. 100) and we're completely stumped as to how we can do the problem without being circular.  The problem reads:

"Use Theorem 7.2 to give another proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra."

Theorem 7.2 reads (with definitions inserted in square brackets):

Let $G$ be a region [an open, connected subset of the complex plane] and let $f$ be an analytic function on $G$ with zeros $a_1,\dots,a_m$ (repeated according to multiplicity).  If $\gamma$ is a closed rectifiable curve in $G$ [closed path of bounded variation] which does not pass through any point $a_k$ and if $\gamma \approx 0$ in $G$ [the winding number $n(\gamma;w)$ is zero for all $w \in \mathbb{C} \backslash G$] then $$\dfrac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\gamma} \dfrac{f'(z)}{f(z)} \; dz = \sum_{k=1}^m n(\gamma;a_k).$$

The only thing we could come up with was to go about the proof by contradiction, but since the formula in the theorem depends on knowing the $a_k$ are zeros, this doesn't have much promise...  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/10535/ways-to-prove-the-fundamental-theorem-of-algebra

Comment: Thanks...  I came across this page when I was searching prior to posting this question, but it didn't look like it contained any proofs using the particular theorem my problem requires...  Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\gamma_R\colon [0,2\pi] \to \mathbb{C};\, \gamma_R(t) = R\cdot e^{it}$. By elementary estimates, one sees that for a polynomial $p$ of degree $n > 0$, there is an $R_0\in (0,+\infty)$ such that $p$ has no zeros outside the open disk $D_{R_0}(0)$. Cauchy's integral theorem says that hence

$$I(R) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma_R} \frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}\,dz$$

is constant on $[R_0,+\infty)$. Use the standard estimate (ML estimate) to see that

$$\lim_{R\to\infty} \int_{\gamma_R} \frac{p'(z)}{p(z)} - \frac{n}{z}\,dz = 0.$$

Comment: I'm confused...  you seem to assume that zeros exist?  Or do you mean that if the zeros do exist, then they must lie in some open disk $D_{R_0}(0)$?

Comment: No, that proves that zeros exist. If $p$ had no zeros, you'd have $I(R) \equiv 0$ by Cauchy's integral theorem as well as by the formula of Theorem 7.2. Showing that $I(R)\neq 0$ therefore proves the existence of zeros. Here, we also get the number of zeros (counting multiplicity).

Comment: Seen the edit to your comment: If there are no zeros, then vacuously all zeros lie in any disk $D_r(0)$. Perhaps if I had written "has no zeros outside the disk" the misunderstanding wouldn't have arisen.

Comment: Hmm.  I'm still a bit confused.  So, if I assume that $p$ has no zeros, then I can calculate that $$\lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{\gamma_R} \dfrac{p'(z)}{p(z)} - \dfrac{n}{z} \; dz = -2 \pi i n.$$  Is this enough to get a contradiction?

Comment: Don't assume anything about whether $p$ has zeros or not. But if you assumed that $p$ has no zeros, you would get $$\int_{\gamma_R} \frac{p'(z)}{p(z)} - \frac{n}{z}\,dz = -2\pi i n$$ for all $R > 0$, which contradicts the fact that the limit as $R\to\infty$ is $0$.